# Diacritic Sensitive sort for objects fetched from core data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

If I want to sort an array of items alphabetically without the option `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch` I need to use a `NSSortDescriptor` with `comparator`

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"SortTitle" ascending:YES comparator:
                                        ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
                                            NSInteger options = NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                            | NSNumericSearch                    // Numbers are compared using numeric value
                                            //  | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch  // Ignores diacritics (â == á == a)
                                            | NSWidthInsensitiveSearch;        // Unicode special width is ignored

                                            return [(NSString*)obj1 compare:obj2 options:options];
```

However such NSSortDescriptor with comparator is not allowed to use in a `NSFetchRequest`.
Therefore should I sort the results *after* fetching them from core data? Is this computationally expensive in terms of performance?

thanks

Comment: Anyone knows how to implement this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There're two approaches I can think of:

1. `Therefore should I sort the results after fetching them from core data?` - that's a one way of doing it. Apple doesn't provide exact string sorting complexities, but I think the bigger problem is the need to first fetch all objects from the persistent store. If you have a lot of data it can hinder the performance. It's best to profile it and only then decide if the performance is acceptable.
2. You can try to use `NSString` methods which are translated into SQL: `localizedStandardCompare:`, `localizedCompare:` or `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`. A sort descriptor using any of these methods can be created in the following way:

   ```
   sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sortTitle"
                                                  ascending:YES
                                                   selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
   ```

   If none of these methods sorts the data the way you want, you can also preprocess it beforehand, e.g. when the title changes you remove the diacritics etc. (see `Normalize User-Generated Content` at [NSHipster - CFStringTransform](http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/)). **UPDATE:** Let me assume the title attribute is named `title` and the title for sorting is named `sortTitle`. In a subclass of `NSManagedObject` you can override `didChangeValueForKey:`as follows:

   ```
   - (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key
   {
       [super didChangeValueForKey:key];

       if ([key isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
           NSString *cleanTitle = [self.title mutableCopy];
           CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)(cleanTitle), NULL, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks, NO);
           self.sortTitle = [cleanTitle copy];
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but if I opt for the latest option, and I decide to preprocess the strings, can I do it at fetch-time? Or do I need to scan one more time the results post fetching? Could you give some hint how to implement it?

Comment: @Patrick: I've just updated my answer. The aim of preprocessing is to have cleaned up data in the persistent store, so you can use Core Data for sorting. If you do the sorting in code, you always have to fetch all objects, even if you only want to display a couple of them. Another advantage of sorting in Core Data is the ease of use of `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Also see the following Apple sample: [Normalized String Searching Using a Core Data Derived Property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/DerivedProperty)